# calculate text for a height, paginate the content

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview

HI

I am trying to paginate the content of UIWebview so i disabled the scroll then the second page will the current view height.
The problem is sometimes the last line of page gets clipped so the first line of the next page too.I want a solution for this situation, if it occurs,it should left the line for the next page OR Is there any solution that calculate the amount of text properly visible within a space OR any other technique to do pagination .
Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Farhan could you help me to do the thing which you have done...

Answer (score 2):

On "webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView", you can get the height of document by this

```
int height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.clientHeight;"] intValue];
```

Then you can readjust your UIWebView frame

Comment: Can you please tell me how to execute this statement..
when i tried it is giving me 0, and can yoy please tell me how to  get the webview width using java script?

Comment: I am currently doing the same but this solution doesn't work out well as sometimes the last line is partially visible .I need a JavaScript function to calculate properly visible text for a limited height.